# How can I index multiple dimensions at once in a Dask Array?

Tags: python, numpy, dask, netcdf

I am trying to run indexing and assignment on a 3D netCDF array loaded into dask to be used for multiprocessing purposes. At the moment Dask does not appear to support direct 3D indexing and assignment so I have been trying to ravel the 3D array to 1D, perform the indexing and assignment, then reshape the result back to 3D at the end, however, this process has proven to be highly memory intensive to the point where my dask workers with 4GB of available memory are unable to complete the task.

The data I am using are the GridRAD set (http://gridrad.org/data.html; netCDF). Getting the data and saving the files are straight-forward enough through XArray, however the data itself needs to have additional processing done on it to be suitable for analysis (The data source creators have written filtering routines that allow for such suitable analysis using numpy here: http://gridrad.org/zip/gridrad_python_software.zip [Provided to show what operations are being performed in dask]). I have converted this script from using numpy arrays to using dask arrays (Namely just switching the definition of numpy functions (IE: np.function) to dask.array functions (IE: da.function), which share the same names and calling conventions.

I stumbled across this git issue in researching potential solutions: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/3096. This git issue seems to detail what I am trying to do, however, the provided examples in there are not descriptive enough for me to understand. I wrote a utility function to remove the .compute() call on the index and have tried to use the lambda approach as detailed in the git issue, but I do not know how to properly use this, here is my current code:

```
def contains_grid0(in_struct, grid):
    lX = len(in_struct["X"])
    lY = len(in_struct["Y"])
    highest = lX * lY

    # If there is a grid, we can find the lowest index.
    if(len(grid) > 0):
        return grid[0] <= highest
    return False

inan = da.flatnonzero(da.asarray(da.isnan(in_struct["ref"]))) # Find bins with NaNs 
if(contains_grid0(in_struct, inan)):
    da.map_blocks(lambda block, idxs=None: idxs[block] = 0.0, block=in_struct["ref"], idxs=inan)
```

This does not work because you cannot assign in a lambda (I do not know how to take the above example and assign from it to test if this will work), but it establishes the proof of concept to what I am trying to accomplish.

Therefore, I am curious if anyone has had to index and assign on a 3D array using Dask and how you have succeeded in doing so in the most memory efficient manner.

Thanks!

Comment: There's a lot going on in your question and it's a little hard to tell what the issue is. Have you tried using xarray and slicing the data that way?

Comment: This question requires people to do a lot of work to figure out what is going on. I recommend rewording it and focusing it on your actual question

Comment: I have modified the question to hopefully be a bit more specific. Essentially, I'm just wondering how to index a 3D dask array when the indexing array is also 3D since native dask does not appear to support this, and trying to ravel to 1D and back to 3D seems to consume a substantial amount of memory.

Comment: Please write a [mcve]. It's your job to isolate the relevant portions of the question, not ours. Consider that if you have a lot of background material, your question is likely unclear.

Comment: The question remains poorly worded. Why end with your question? Start with it. Very little of the preceding info is relevant